# Text Spacing in Reportlab python

Tags: python, reportlab

I am trying to make a big gap between two pieces of text in report lab/Python.

For example this is my input: `1st word 2nd word`

I am using Paragraphs for example on how I draw a string `document.append(Paragraph("1st word"))`.

I tried the spacer function and it just made it move down a line (`Spacer(20,0)`).

And I tried just adding spaces into the string but that merged them (input: `1st word                  2nd word`, output: `1st word 2nd word`).

Comment: Hello Just for you to know the desired output is 1st word then 2nd word but a big space in between them for some reason stack overflow is not showing the other spaces

Comment: sorry didn't know I could post my own answer

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

`'\t' * 3` means 3 tab characters, you can adjust it to use space or different multiples of tab/space.

```
a = 'hello'
b = 'world'
gap = '\t' * 3
print(a + gap + b)
```

which outputs: `hello           world`

Comment: sorry I didn't format it well I will change it and it would work just I tried that in report lab and it just merged it same thing happened to the question after I surpassed one space it just didn't show it

Comment: seems to be an issue with the stack, unfortunately. Was my code helpful at all?

Comment: sadly no I still have the same problem with it merging it together

Answer (score 0):

Solved: So I know I couldn't find much info about this online so for the ones who are desperate I just used text objects here is a really good tutorial on it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jmNB3-4Hca4&list=PLN0iJDXT7K2vfX7WztJckkhjYbsns1u4H&index=4

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).